# QT6 в Visual Studio Community 2022

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022, qt6

Установил QT6 под windows 10. Пробую запускать штатные примеры.

Из под QT creator всё компилируется.
Из PowerShell 7 команды: qmake + mingw32-make тоже успешно компилируют примеры.

В Visual Studio Community 2022 установил плагин QT Visual Studio Tools.
Он запросил путь к qmake.

qmake нашёлся в двух каталогах:

C:\Qt\Tools\QtDesignStudio\qt6_design_studio_reduced_version\bin

C:\Qt\6.6.1\mingw_64\bin

На каталог \mingw_64\bin студия ругается что там qmake "не правильный", хотя в PowerShell именно этот каталог нормально компилирует.

Каталог с \QtDesignStudio\ студия признаёт и успешно открывает QT проекты, но при попытке компиляции пишет:

> Ошибка    LNK1104 не удается открыть файл
> "C:\Qt\Tools\QtDesignStudio\qt6_design_studio_reduced_version\lib\Qt6EntryPointd.lib"

В этом каталоге есть Qt6EntryPointd.prl, а Qt6EntryPointd.lib нет ни в одном из подкаталогов C:\QT\.

Где взять этот Qt6EntryPointd.lib или как научить Visual Studio Community 2022 без него обходиться? (ведь QT creator и qmake + mingw32-make из командной строки без него обходятся).

Answer (score 0):

Задал этот вопрос в техподдержку QT, получил ответ:
"укажите путь к полной установке Qt, т. е. C:\Qt\6.6.1\msvc2019_64\bin\qmake.exe, вместо сокращенной версии, поставляемой с Qt Design Studio."

Осталась проблема в том, что у меня в папке C:\Qt\6.6.1 нет папки msvc2019_64\bin.

После этого один товарищ посоветовал мне не связываться с QT6, ибо она сырая, и осваивать зрелую QT5.
Переустановил QT с учётом этого совета - появилась папка C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\bin содержащая qmake.exe и все нужные *.dll. Теперь моя Visual Studio нормально собирает и запускает пробный QT проект.

Comment: сложно сказать что не так. Собираю свою программы и на Qt5 и на Qt6 но только в Qt Designer используя систему сборки cmake. Рекомендую перейти на нее. (масштаб комментариев маленький для подробностей). Конечно, среда VS лучше, но... не всегда.